# Do I really need an ERN to publish an iOS in the app store?

Tags: ios

I'm new to this forum, so I'm not sure if this is the correct place or way to ask. Forgive me if it's not. I have an app in the app store that uses the Flickr API and a friend of mine recently pointed me to this blog post about how if I use an API I need an ERN or something like that: https://carouselapps.com/2015/12/09/mac-ios-applications-breaking-rules-removed/

I asked the freelancer coder that built it for me and he said that he knew nothing about it and told me I could ask here. Is this true? do I need to get an ERN to publish an app in the iOS store when it's using the Flickr API?

Comment: Look at question 2 of the Export Compliance section. It would be unlikely that your app didn't meet one of those exemptions.

Comment: So, you mean the answer is yes then, right?